# Iterate over a dictionary with lists to create n subplots

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, matplotlib

[Type of chart that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxhgY.png)
So I have a dictionary with several lists:

```
{'A' : [1,2,4,6,7,8,10],
'B' : [1,2,4,6,4,3,7],
'C' : [3,2,1,6,2,3,4]}
```

At the same time, these dictionaries are generated by a function, and they have different sizes, but they never exceed... 6,7?

I need to find a way to plot (matplotlib) as many stacked charts as the number of entries in my dictionary, having the values in the dictionary as my y_axis and their index as x_axis. I understad I'd never to insert them into a loop but I don't know what's the best way to do that in matplotlib as I am not well-versed in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a way to do it without looping, but here's a way to do it with looping. Unless you have loads and loads of these dictionaries this should work fine:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = {'A' : [1,2,4,6,7,8,10],'B' : [1,2,4,6,4,3,7], 'C' : [3,2,1,6,2,3,4]}
fig, ax = sns.plt.subplots(len(data), 1, figsize=(7,5))
for a,key in zip(ax,data.keys() ):
    y = data[key]
    n = len(y)
    x = np.linspace(1,n,n)
    a.plot(x,y)
    # add labels/titles and such here

plt.show()
```

Gives the following:[image]

If you don't have Seaborn, replace

```
fig, ax = sns.plt.subplots(len(data), 1, figsize=(7,5))
```

with the plain matplotlib

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(data), 1, figsize=(7,5))
```

Comment: Hi! This works well for small amounts of dictionaries but crashes for large amounts of dictionaries (>35)! What would my alternative be for those data sets?

Comment: can you tell me a bit more? what is causing the crash or what error is being thrown?

Comment: Now I can't replicate the error anymore. Good, I gues. Btw, how could I make the label of each subplot be its key in the dictionary?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Don't forget to accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: Sure. Would you help me out with the labels?

Comment: `a.set_title(key)` should do the trick. put that inside the loop at the end.